# Use CalendarView & FrameLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, xml

I'm looking for a way to use the CalendarView and the FrameLayout in a ScrollView. My first idea was like this:

```
<ScrollView
    ...

    <CalendarView
        ...
    />

    <FrameLayout
        ...
    />
</ScrollView>
```

but for some reason the XML-File doesn't display the FrameLayout. However the ScrollView is very important and the reason why I use the FrameLayout is, because I'm using multiple views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<ScrollView>

<LinearLayout>
    ...

    <CalendarView
        ...
    />

    <FrameLayout
        ...
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also kindly note that Frame Layout wont show in design preview if width and height set as "wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` can have only one view as child.

```
<ScrollView> 
  <LinearLayout>
   ...

   <CalendarView
    ...
   />

   <FrameLayout
    ...
   />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>`
```

Comment: An example of how to address the issue would really help the OP.  e.g. using a vertical stack layout to host the multiple controls